# How do you cancel a batch of Stripe Subscriptions?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

Business went under, what do I do? The Dashboard doesn't let me cancel all subscriptions and schedules in a batch at once with a simple command.

Answer (score 3):

I had to create what I call the "end of the world" script for when you need to cancel all your customers' subscriptions, or at least a fair number of them.

Steps:

1. Go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/subscriptions
2. Click Export *(and filter according to your needs if you're lucky to keep a few customers)*
3. Copy and paste the subscription ids into this script or parse the ids from csv file into the variable
4. Run it.
5. Check https://dashboard.stripe.com/subscriptions again to make sure it's all gone
6. Check https://dashboard.stripe.com/subscription_schedules in case you had schedules
7. Check https://dashboard.stripe.com/invoices?closed=false&status=open in case you need to stop collection on any invoices

`fml.js`

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')('your api key goes here');

const subscriptions = [
    // paste all subscriptions ids here or parse the array from the first column of the CSV file
];

async function cancelSubscription(s) {
    try {
        const deleted = await stripe.subscriptions.del(s);
        console.log(deleted.id);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

function delay(t, val) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(val);
        }, t);
    });
}

(async () => {
    for (const sub of subscriptions) {
        await cancelSubscription(sub)
        await delay(1000) // this delay prevents going over the API limit, you can decrease it
        // but you'll miss the opportunity to say goodbye to the ids rolling through your screen
    }
})()
```

Wish you all the best and may you never need to use this piece of code.

Comment: This is nice. In a real world situation, you would probably want to auto-refund as well, so it would be nice to include that in the sample code also :-).

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to cancel all subscriptions. But you could do it this way:

1. List all subscriptions using [this endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list)
2. Then cancel each of the subscription using [this endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel)

In Node.js it would look something like this:

```js
const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list();
subscriptions.autoPagingEach(subscription => {
  await stripe.subscriptions.del(subscription.id);
});
```